# Docker container - yank text using xclip

Tags: linux, docker, xclip

I am having issues related with `xclip` in a docker container.

```
echo "text" | xclip
```

which raises the error: `Error: Can't open display: (null)`.

How can I programmatically add some text to host's clipboard from the container (in an OS independent way if possible)?

Thank you in advance.

### UPDATE

`DISPLAY` env variable is not set. How can I set it correctly?

Comment: Maybe your $DISPLAY is not set.

Comment: Yes, it is not @Ashok (sorry, I will update the question). But how can I set it up correctly?

Comment: DISPLAY=:0 xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: Should I do that in the container or in the host?

Comment: Furthermore, I do not have an SSH folder in my container

Answer (score 0):

Not OS independent, but you can mount your host's X11 socket:

```bash
docker run --volume /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -it CONTAINER
```

More info: http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/